# Solenoid Electrical Characteristics

Tags: arduino, solenoid

I'm looking at [this](http://content2.smcetech.com/pdf/VDW.pdf) line of solenoids, but I'm not sure how to figure out the electrical characteristics.

If the solenoid is rated at 12VDC, and 3W, does that mean I can strap it across a 12V supply, and the solenoid won't melt? As in the manufacturer built in a 48 Ohm series resistance to limit the current to 0.25A and I don't have to rely on something else in my circuit to limit the current?

Also, assuming I wire it like this:

[image: Solenoid hookup schematic]

How long does it take for these things to de-magnetize in general? Microseconds? Milliseconds? It should be determined by the inductance of the coil, but the inductance isn't specified in any kind of solenoid datasheet I can find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Just said, the voltaqe rating of a solenoid is what you use.  The power rating tells you how much power it will take to keep it energized.  3W / 12V = 250mA, which is what the solenoid will draw in steady state with 12V applied.

Manufacturers often list a family of solenoids with a particular wattage, because that is what remains constant accross the various coils they offer in that family.  To keep the magnetic force the same, the same number of turn-amps is required.  Let's say they make a variant with twice the number of turns.  That means it only needs half the current to achieve the necessary magnetism.  To keep the physical size of the coil the same, the wire diameter needs to be 1/sqrt(2) of the original version, which is half the cross-sectional area.  Half the area means twice the resistance per length, but the new coil is twice as long so overall has 4 times the resistance.  To get half the current of the original version, you have to apply twice the voltage to this new coil.  Note that in the example the voltage doubled but the current halved, which means the power stayed the same.  I haven't looked, but the manufacturer probably offers otherwise identical solenoids with different voltage and current combinations that all come out to about 3W, like 6V at 500mA, 24V at 125mA, etc.

As for the turn off speed, that is limited by the mechanical part of the solenoid.  The magnetic field is proportional to the current instantaneously.  If you make the current stop, the magnetic field will stop too.  Whatever was held in place by that magnetic field still has inertia, and will therefore take some time to react.

Relays, which are solenoids with a well controlled and known mass to move, can switch in a few ms for fast ones to a few 10s of ms for ordinary ones.  Generally solenoids move heavier things, so the system takes longer to react when the coil current is shut off.  This all depends on the mass that is moving and how much force is pushing it.  See Newton's second law.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when an electromechanical device like a relay or solenoid is rated 12V, it typically means you can put 12V directly across it. The 'built in' resistance is usually just the resistance of the copper in the coil.

Solenoids and relays are relatively slow to react - nowehere near microsecond speeds. The best you could hope for is probably on the order of a millisecond.

Comment: In cases where higher performance is needed, you can achieve faster transitions by using a much higher voltage to fight the reluctance, with a current-regulating architecture to insure that the current eventually reached does not exceed the specs.  This is fairly standard for something like a stepper motor where the coils must be pulsed quickly to full current if the motor is going to spin at a high speed without too much loss of torque.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - well, sure. However, did you look at the proffered wiring diagram? I didn't think the OP was too worried about high performance stepper control, yet.

Comment: Sorry about the typo - in my earlier comment is should say "to fight the reactance" rather than reluctance.  Unfortunately comment's aren't editable beyond a short time window.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the rated voltage indefinitely IF the solenoid is rated for 100 percent duty cycle, or continuous duty. Three watts is a fairly small amount of power for a solenoid. I don't see any duty cycle rating offhand, so these are surely 100 percent rated. For a rating of, say, 20 percent, you would have a maximum on time of perhaps 10 seconds, and you would need the off time to be at least 40 seconds for each 10 seconds of on time to insure you stay within the 20 percent duty cycle rating.

The resistance or 48 ohms is the actual resistance of the wire that makes up the solenoid coil. This dissipates the power as heat in the solenoid, just as a resistor of the same value would.

For turn-off (and turn-on) time, as others answered, it's often in the tens of milliseconds, and is determined as much as by mechanical characteristics as electrical characteristics. If the exact value is important to you, look through more datasheets, call the manufacturer's technical support, or you may have to test it yourself. Manufacturers generally don't characterize parameters of a device that aren't seen as important to customers.

Answer (score 0):

One factor not yet mentioned is that the rate at which a solenoid turns off will be a function of the reverse voltage it is allowed to induce.  Placing a diode directly across the coil will limit the voltage the transistor sees to about 12.7 volts, but may make the solenoid's release a bit "spongy".  Adding e.g. a 12V Zener in series with that diode (the Zener polarity should be opposite that of the diode) would allow the solenoid to turn off faster, but would cause Q1 to see closer to 25 volts.  Note also that the Zener would see a peak current of about 3 amps and a peak power of about 36 watts; its average power dissipation would be much less, but it would have to absorb a certain amount of energy each time the coil switches off.  If the coil is operated once per second, one might get by with no heat sink, but if it's operated 20x/second, a heat sink for the diode may be needed.